# Handle umlauts (non-ASCII-characters) in postfix sendmail (sending mail on console)

Tags: utf-8, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta, diacritics

I wrote a C++ application that needs to send emails.

It does this by calling

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -f [sender] -t
```

and then writing the mail headers and body to the standard input of the sendmail process.

Everything works fine - except for umlauts or other non-ASCII characters.
How can I make them working correctly?

I already tried to set

```
Content-Type: plain-text; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

as a mail header and also

```
Content-Type: plain-text; charset=UTF-8
```

didn't change anything. Seems like this header is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything other than ASCII in an email message should typically be encoded either as [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) or [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` and `Content-Type` headers are then set accordingly so that the recipient knows how to decode the message back to non-ASCII text.

Here's a bash example that illustrates how this can be done on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
message="Hellö ümläüts"
encoded=$(base64 <<< "$message")

/usr/sbin/sendmail -t <<< "From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Dear friend
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

$encoded"
```

You need to specify whatever character encoding was used to convert the string to binary before the data was base64 encoded.

This example uses utf-8, because that is a common platform default so most shells would use utf-8 when converting the string to binary and passing it to `base64` on stdin.

Comment: What should the Content-Type be if you're going to encode your message with quoted printables (and not use a bse64 transfer encoding)? Does this even make sense?

Comment: @James In that case you don't need to change `Content-Type`, but `Content-Transfer-Encoding` needs to change to `quoted-printable`.

Answer (score 0):

following this question answer, i've written a bash function to send an email to recipients. The function send utf-8 encoded mails and work with utf-8 chars in subject and content by doing a base64 encode.

To send a plain text email:

```
send_email "plain" "from@domain.com" "subject" "contents" "to@domain.com" "to2@domain.com" "to3@domain.com" ...
```

To send a HTML email:

```
send_email "html" "from@domain.com" "subject" "contents" "to@domain.com" "to2@domain.com" "to3@domain.com" ...
```

Here is the function code.

```
# Send a email to recipients.
#
# @param string $content_type Email content mime type: 'html' or 'plain'.
# @param string $from_address Sender email.
# @param string $subject Email subject.
# @param string $contents Email contents.
# @param array $recipients Email recipients.
function send_email() {
  [[ ${#} -lt 5 ]] && exit 1

  local content_type="${1}"
  local from_address="${2}"
  local subject="${3}"
  local contents="${4}"

  # Remove all args but recipients.
  shift 4

  local encoded_contents="$(base64 <<< "${contents}")"
  local encoded_subject="=?utf-8?B?$(base64 --wrap=0 <<< "${subject}")?="

  for recipient in ${@}; do
    if [[ -n "${recipient}" ]]; then
    sendmail -f "${from_address}" "${recipient}" \
        <<< "Subject: ${encoded_subject}
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: ${from_address}
To: ${recipient}
Content-Type: text/${content_type}; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

${encoded_contents}"
    fi
  done

  return 0
} # send_message()
```

Hope this can help you.